# how get session in symfony3

Tags: session, symfony-3.3

I want to start session in symfony 3.3 for this way:

```
$session = new Session();
                $session->start();
                $session->set("caso","sesion_GeFormX");
                $session->set("id",$usuario->getIdUsuario());
```

but i dont know how can i get this session in other controller o bundle (the rest of the app)

i tried with it

```
$r_session = $this->get('session');
```

but it does not work, and i used the request but i think that in symfony3 it is diferent to symfony 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the session value by name.

Replace

```
$r_session = $this->get('session');
```

with

```
$r_session = $this->get('caso');
```

This will give you result as "**sesion_GeFormX**".

**Session setup in symfony 3**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

//setting up new session
$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set session attributes
$session->set('name', 'Drak');

// get session attributes
$session->get('name');
```